# $W^0$ is a subspace of $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

If $W\subset V$ is a subspace of $V$, and $W^0=\{f\in V^* | f(v)=0~\forall~v\in W\}$, then how do I show that $W^0$ is a subspace of $V^*$?

Comment: I know I have to take two elements $f$ and $g$ in $W^0$ and show that $cf+g\in W^0$, but I'm not sure how, and how do I specifically show that it is a subspace of $V^*$?

Comment: I have here written down that $(cf+g)(v) \leadsto 0$, but what does this show?

Comment: that's it. since (cf+g)(v)=0, you've already shown that $W^0$ is a subspace of $V^*$.

Comment: I see . . . How unexciting . . .

Comment: So . . . It's a subspace because $f\in V^*$? Why does this proof seem too simple?

Comment: No... it's a subspace, because if $f,g \in W^0$, then $cf+g \in W^0$. Recall what is required for something to be a subspace.

Comment: No, I know that. I'm just saying that I can't say it's a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ or $\cdots$.

Comment: OK, never mind. I don't think I'm getting across what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I meant, that it's a subspace of $V^*$ in particular because $f\in V^*$, right?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh, that last comment of yours doesn't make much sense if you don't say what $\,f\,$ is...

Comment: @BarisaBarukh It's a subspace of $V^\ast$ because it's a subset of $V^\ast$ (by the very definition you give in the question) that is closed under the vector space operations of $V^\ast$. Sometimes, all there is to do is just apply the definitions you have directly.

Comment: That title is somewhat distruptive -- what does it mean? Is the meaning any different from that of "Is $W^0$ a subspace of $V^*$"?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $W^{0}$ is subset of $V^{*}$ and for each $f,g\in W^{0}$ and $\alpha \in F$ we have $(\alpha f+g)(v)=\alpha f(v)+g(v)=0+0= \forall v \in W$ ($f,g$ are linear functionals), so $\alpha f+g \in W^{0}$.

It is subset of $V^{*}$ and itself is vector space too, so it will be a subspace of $V^{*}$.